# Is Microphone class supported on any Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, audio, microphone

I saw a lot of issues about using Microphone in Flash on Android on the Internet.

But my own flash applet does not work, saying "mic not detected". Also there is a note in AS3 reference, that Microphone class is not supported on any mobile device.

Where is the truth?

Answer (score 2):

It defintely works with AIR on Android, if you create *.apk files. You just need to set the manifest file to allow microphone access. [See here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html).

Edit:

Silly me, this is about online. Well, if it says in the official Adobe refernce that this does not work, then I fear it really does not.

Comment: How these links can be explained then (1) http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/07/voicenotes-for-android-sample-app-using-flex-air-and-the-microphone-api/ (2)
http://www.packtpub.com/article/flash-development-for-android-audio-input-via-microphone

Comment: People do not know they are writing?

Comment: Well it does work like these links suggest when compiling an apk with AIR or when using a normal swf via any Browser, but the question was if the online swf (not AIR compiled!) also works when you are browsing with an Android device. And if the official Adobe statement is "no", then it is "no" ;) But I don't know the source for that statement. The OP found that :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understood the circumstances under which it can work? How should I compile SWF to have microphone working? What is "normal swf" and how it is differs from "abnormal" swf?

Comment: What I am talking about is the platform that you can set for your Flash application. It can be Flash Player (version 9, 10, 11, etc.) or AIR. Swfs that are compiled for the Flash Player platform I meant with "normal" swfs. But you can also compile for the AIR platform and package it (to get an installer *.apk, *.exe, *.air, etc.), which is then a desktop (or mobile) application that cannot be embedded into a browser like a "normal" swf can, because it does not use the Flash Player platform.

Comment: And if Adobe says that a "normal" swf, embedded in a website using the Flash Player platform does not support Microphone on Android, then I would take their word for it. But could you show the document where this is stated?

Comment: I understand all this but don't understand will microphone work SOMEHOW or not. And if yes, then HOW? You think that if I make standalone app for AIR it will find microphone on android? This means that android has two different runtimes for playing flash -- full and resticted?

Comment: No this means, that Android has only one runtime for a Flash application: The Flash Player. And I don't know if this offers microphone access on Android. But if Adobe says "no", then there is no SOMEHOW ;) But you can always make a standalone AIR application out of your ActionScript and Flash code. And an AIR application definitely offers microphone access that works on Android (for that please follow the link in my answer). In general, I really think you should have a look at Flash and AIR to get into the matter a bit better.

Comment: On which runtime engine AIR application runs?

Comment: It is similar to a Flash application using the Flash Player as runtime. AIR applications run in the AIR runtime. You can have users download that runtime in order to use an AIR application, or bundle the runtime together with the app (adds about 8MB).